# How to convert the following value in meaningful value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flask, flask-restful

I'm getting a response from Flask API like this

"நம்பிக்கை வைக்கும் பேசும் உறவு வைக்கும் அன்பு தான் கிடைக்கும்"

but when I pass it through the Flutter It shows like some ASCII representation like this

"\u0ba8\u0b9f\u0bc1\u0ba8\u0bbf\u0bb2\u0bc8 \u0b85\u0ba9\u0bcd\u0baa\u0bbf\u0ba9\u0bcd".

I tried to convert it in frontend but I couldn't convert it as I expected

Comment: Where does it show ascii representation? In console or inside flutter app on device?

Answer (score 1):

The response you are seeing is the Unicode escape sequence representation of Tamil characters.

You can convert them to their corresponding Tamil characters using the `dart:convert` library:

```
 String unicodeResponse = "\u0ba8\u0b9f\u0bc1\u0ba8\u0bbf\u0bb2\u0bc8 \u0b85\u0ba9\u0bcd\u0baa\u0bbf\u0ba9\u0bcd";
 String decodedResponse = json.decode('"$unicodeResponse"');
```

`decodedResponse` is the meaningful value you want.

Comment: It's not working as you mentioned It shows a exception as follow "Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
 \u0ba8\u0b9f\u0bc1\u0ba8\u0bbf\u0bb2\u0bc8 \u0b85\u0ba9\u0bcd\u0baa\u0bbf\..."